# Can I shorten lengthy file paths in Notepad++'s recently opened files menu?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ keeps a list of recently opened documents in the `File` menu.

Unfortunately, these file paths can sometimes be somewhat lengthy, meaning the `File` menu can expand to comically large sizes.

[image: [File menu with lengthy paths]

Is there any way to truncate or shorten these file paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can change how the paths are displayed via `Settings → Preferences → Recent Files History`.

[image: Recent Files History menu]

You can either customize the maximum path length...

[image: Max length - 70 characters]

Or ignore paths and only show file names...

[image: Filename only]